# Get Device/OS version and country/language codes in a Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get device information in a windows universal app and I'm having trouble finding which packages provide the os version, country code, and language code.

```
private void SetGeneratedFields()
    {
        _fields.objectType = "user";

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fields.userID))
        {
            _fields.userID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        _fields.sessionID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var deviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();

        _fields.appVersion = this.GetAppVersion();
        _fields.operatingSystem = deviceInformation.OperatingSystem;
        _fields.operatingSystemVersion = "?";
        _fields.countryCode = "?";
        _fields.languageCode = "?";
        _fields.deviceType = deviceInformation.FriendlyName;
    }

    private string GetAppVersion()
    {
        string appVersion = string.Format("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                Package.Current.Id.Version.Major,
                Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor,
                Package.Current.Id.Version.Build,
                Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision);
        return appVersion;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the OS version is not possible (yet). There are other questions dealing with this and most answers boil down to the fact that this makes sense since only 8.1 devices run Windows Runtime code. So if you're in a Windows Runtime app you automatically know that this has to be 8.1 (this is at least true for Windows Phone). I guess Microsoft will add API calls for this once Windows 10 is out.

You can get the language and country code like this:

```
// Returns the following format: en-US
var tag = Windows.Globalization.Language.CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag;
```